# Adicionando 2 linhas de campos em um Banco de Dados usando C# (MVC)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo uma ActionResult dentro de um controle para efetivar alguns dados de compra. A idéia é fazer a compra e venda de produtos (nesse caso Moedas),negativando a `Quantidade` e positivando `Valor` no caso de venda e o contrário no caso de Compra, e pegando esses valores e mais alguns campos para serem armazenados numa tabela.

Só que na hora de enviar os dados para um banco de dados `db.Movimento` os campos não saem corretamente. Na mostragem dos dados da tabela, a primeira entrada sai os dados corretamente, com excessão do `Cd_moeda` e `Nm_moeda`

Na segunda entrada, não sai nada, fica tudo em `NULL`

Como eu faço para poder adicionar as duas entradas corretamente?

Código relatado:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Efetivar([Bind(Include = "Codigo,Dat,Tipo_ope,Cd_loja,Nm_loja,Cd_moeda,Nm_moeda,Cd_conta,Nm_conta,Historico,Descricao,Quantidade,Valor,Preco,Invoice")] OperacaoCV operacaoCV)
    {
        string wId = (string)Session["Cd_loja"];

        //operacaoCV = db.OperacaoCVs.Find(operacaoCV.Codigo);

        double wValor1;
        double wValor2;
        if (operacaoCV.Tipo_ope == "C")            //se o tipo operacao for Compra (C)
        {
            wValor1 = operacaoCV.Valor * (-1);
            wValor2 = operacaoCV.Quantidade;
        }
        else                                                           //se o tipo operacao for Venda
        {
            wValor1 = operacaoCV.Valor;
            wValor2 = operacaoCV.Quantidade * (-1);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           
            Movimento mv = new Movimento();
            mv.Cd_conta = operacaoCV.Cd_conta;
            mv.Cd_loja = operacaoCV.Cd_loja;
            mv.Nm_conta = operacaoCV.Nm_conta;
            mv.Nm_moeda = "Real";
            mv.Cd_moeda = 1;
            mv.Dat = operacaoCV.Dat;
            mv.Nm_conta = operacaoCV.Nm_conta;
            mv.Tp_operacao = operacaoCV.Tipo_ope;
            mv.Preco = operacaoCV.Preco;
            mv.Quantidade = operacaoCV.Quantidade;
            mv.Valor = wValor1;
            mv.Historico = operacaoCV.Historico;
            mv.Invoice = operacaoCV.Invoice;

            db.Movimento.Add(mv);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Movimento mv2 = new Movimento();
            mv.Cd_conta = operacaoCV.Cd_conta;
            mv.Cd_loja = operacaoCV.Cd_loja;
            mv.Nm_conta = operacaoCV.Nm_conta;
            mv.Nm_moeda = operacaoCV.Nm_moeda;
            mv.Cd_moeda = operacaoCV.Cd_moeda;
            mv.Dat = operacaoCV.Dat;
            mv.Nm_conta = operacaoCV.Nm_conta;
            mv.Tp_operacao = operacaoCV.Tipo_ope;
            mv.Preco = operacaoCV.Preco;
            mv.Quantidade = operacaoCV.Quantidade;
            mv.Valor = wValor2;
            mv.Historico = operacaoCV.Historico;
            mv.Invoice = operacaoCV.Invoice;

            
            db.Movimento.Add(mv2);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(operacaoCV);
    }
```

Comment: Na segunda parte o prefixo não deveria ser `mv2` e não `mv`? Me pareceu meio estranho este wValor2 e Quantidade.

Comment: Era realmente isso. Nem passou pela minha cabeça, muito obrigado!
Na parte do Quantidade é suposto a pegar ao valor e a quantidade, e em uma entrada desses 2 campos é o oposto do outro
Ex.--
Tipo operação -> Compra ;
logo no mv será -(valor) e +(quantidade)
enquanto no mv2 irá ser +(valor) e -(quantidade).
É uma operação de transferência de moedas.

Comment: É que você atribui a `mv.Valor` wValor1, obtido de valor, e na segunda parte wValor2, obtido de quantidade.

Answer (score 1):

Olhe para o seu segundo insert, ele esta com "mv", que é o primeiro insert tem que colocar o "mv2".

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Efetivar([Bind(Include = "Codigo,Dat,Tipo_ope,Cd_loja,Nm_loja,Cd_moeda,Nm_moeda,Cd_conta,Nm_conta,Historico,Descricao,Quantidade,Valor,Preco,Invoice")] OperacaoCV operacaoCV)
{
    string wId = (string)Session["Cd_loja"];

    //operacaoCV = db.OperacaoCVs.Find(operacaoCV.Codigo);

    double wValor1;
    double wValor2;
    if (operacaoCV.Tipo_ope == "C")            //se o tipo operacao for Compra (C)
    {
        wValor1 = operacaoCV.Valor * (-1);
        wValor2 = operacaoCV.Quantidade;
    }
    else                                                           //se o tipo operacao for Venda
    {
        wValor1 = operacaoCV.Valor;
        wValor2 = operacaoCV.Quantidade * (-1);
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       
        Movimento mv = new Movimento();
        mv.Cd_conta = operacaoCV.Cd_conta;
        mv.Cd_loja = operacaoCV.Cd_loja;
        mv.Nm_conta = operacaoCV.Nm_conta;
        mv.Nm_moeda = "Real";
        mv.Cd_moeda = 1;
        mv.Dat = operacaoCV.Dat;
        mv.Nm_conta = operacaoCV.Nm_conta;
        mv.Tp_operacao = operacaoCV.Tipo_ope;
        mv.Preco = operacaoCV.Preco;
        mv.Quantidade = operacaoCV.Quantidade;
        mv.Valor = wValor1;
        mv.Historico = operacaoCV.Historico;
        mv.Invoice = operacaoCV.Invoice;

        db.Movimento.Add(mv);
        db.SaveChanges();

        Movimento mv2 = new Movimento();
        mv2.Cd_conta = operacaoCV.Cd_conta;
        mv2.Cd_loja = operacaoCV.Cd_loja;
        mv2.Nm_conta = operacaoCV.Nm_conta;
        mv2.Nm_moeda = operacaoCV.Nm_moeda;
        mv2.Cd_moeda = operacaoCV.Cd_moeda;
        mv2.Dat = operacaoCV.Dat;
        mv2.Nm_conta = operacaoCV.Nm_conta;
        mv2.Tp_operacao = operacaoCV.Tipo_ope;
        mv2.Preco = operacaoCV.Preco;
        mv2.Quantidade = operacaoCV.Quantidade;
        mv2.Valor = wValor2;
        mv2.Historico = operacaoCV.Historico;
        mv2.Invoice = operacaoCV.Invoice;

        
        db.Movimento.Add(mv2);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(operacaoCV);
}
```